# django request.session.clear() 和request.session.flush() difference？

Tags: python, django

django request.session.clear() 和request.session.flush()  difference？

What environment is used separately?

```
request.session.clear()
```

or

```
request.session.flush()
```

doc is say:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

`flush` calls `clear` then `delete` methods.

In the case of the DB session, It removes the current session data from the database and regenerates the key.

`clear` method just erase some attributes of the session object.

Almost everything is written in this [file](https://github.com/davitovmasyan/django/blob/master/django/contrib/sessions/backends/base.py).